# Can I rotate part of the mesh while reserving topology?

Tags: modeling, mesh

So, I have a mesh (a tie fighter, actually) with this plate on the end:
[image]

Sadly, the plate is misaligned with the rest of the spaceship.  I need to rotate it.  However, this drags the vertices that lead from the arm to the plate and leads to some very funny results.

I suppose I could detach it, rotate it, and then reattach it, but then it would no longer truly be connected to the rest of the mesh.. .and I'm ramping up to model for a 3D printer, so I'd like to work this out!

Comment: Do you have proportional editing enabled? (press `O` to toggle)

Comment: you can disconnect, rotate reconnect like you said, but then remove doubles.. it would be 100% attached.

Comment: Hmm.. how exactly do we reconnect it then?  I'm not sure what I was gonna do would even leave doubles..

Comment: @user1833028 You can merge vertices with Alt+M http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Vertices If you dont want to merge them you can also move the 3d Cursor to vertices or faces or the middle of edge loops with Alt+S. Then you could set the origin of the separated part to the point which shall be moved there and use Alt+S to move it there.

Answer (score 1):

Its actually simple :)

First select the edge loop you need to seperate with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Then select the other remaining edges by right clicking on them....

When you're done selecting just the plate press <kbd>P</kbd>
Then choose Separate by Selection

Now rotate it as you like....

**Now is the tricky part....**

I'm not sure how others do this, but I do it in this way...

suppose the uppermost cube is your plate and the lower one as your main ship...

[image]

Now we've separated these two in the previous step...
Now make them a single object by  <kbd>Shift+RMB</kbd> selecting each object, and then pressing  <kbd>Ctrl+J</kbd> .....

[image]

Now go to edit mode and go to vertex select mode... 
and press  <kbd>B</kbd>  to box select the plate from Orthographic View (<kbd>Num 5</kbd>) or a comfortable angle...

For yours it may be right side (<kbd>Num 3</kbd>)
then select all the edges to be joined....

In your case it's just two edge loops (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>)....

[image]

Then press <kbd>F</kbd> to make faces between them...

Now, it mightn't be the best technique but I found it works for me...
Hope it helps :)

Comment: `Ctrl + E` for Edge operations menu, then **Bridge Two Edge Loops** might also be an option.